# Any problems with ob_start?

Tags: php

Should we always use ob_start in our applications?

Comment: Not if it's a php-Gtk application.

Comment: Billy, if you want a more specific answer you should edit your question. Tell us about what kind of applications you build. And more importantly tell us why you think you need `ob_start()` in the first place. There are multiple reasons and use cases; good and outdated ones. (I didn't downvote; this time.)

Answer (score 10):

No, only use it if you plan to use output buffering in your project...

Answer (score 5):

Only when you need it and it's the right tool for the job.